# How to resize images in table

Tags: c#, asp.net

Now, the image my table can be viewed but I want to resize it. How can I set the height and width.

```
TableCell c0 = new TableCell();
c0.Text = string.Format("<img src='"+c.Movie_image+"'/>");
```

c.Movie_image is the image string from database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

```
c0.Text = string.Format("<img src='"+c.Movie_image+"' style='height:100px;width:100px;'/>");
```

or a class attribute is preferred

```
c0.Text = string.Format("<img src='"+c.Movie_image+"' class='classname'/>");
```